# Can someone give an ELI5 explanation of what each component of 'with open()' is doing when I pickle?

Tags: python, pickle, with-statement

I've used this syntax many, many times to pickle a file, but the truth is I don't understand what is actually happening. I just know that it gives me the result that I want.

```
with open('some_model_name.pickle', 'wb') as to_write:
   pickle.dump(some_model_object, to_write)
```

But what is actually happening? What if I don't specify `wb`? What is `as to_write`?

Same with when I read my model back in:

```
with open(path+'some_model_name.pickle', 'rb') as to_read:
  some_model_object = pickle.load(to_read)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "wb" is shorthand for "write in binary mode".  If you don't specify "wb" you will get the default mode of `open`, which is read in text mode. In that case, the call to `pickle.dump` would then fail, because the file was opened in read-only mode and you try to write some bytes.

The binding `as to_write` means to assign the return-value of the `open` call to a local variable named `to_write`. A similar way to do the same thing, without using a context manager ("with statement") may look like:

```
try:
    to_write = open('some_model_name.pickle', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(some_model_object, to_write)
finally:
    to_write.close()
```

This is a simplified version, a more complete equivalent is given in the docs link at the end of this answer.

The second code-block shown in the question is analogous, except it's opening the file "some_model_name.pickle" in "read binary" mode "rb", which is appropriate because `pickle.load` (reading bytes) is used here instead of `pickle.dump` (writing bytes).

Relevant docs links for the parts I've described:

- [*Built-in Function `open`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)
- [*The `with` statement*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

Comment: Thanks so much, @wim. Sometimes just having a plain, very simplified explanation is all that's needed. I've read the documentation, but that path just keeps going deeper and deeper into the woods, and I was getting lost. I appreciate your help!

Comment: This is only partially correct. The as statement assigns the result of the call to `__enter__()` on whatever `open()` returns to `to_write`, which is the same only in this specific case.

Comment: @RichardNeumann You're right, but in the case of built-in open, that's an unnecessary complication to go into for an "ELI5 explanation", given `open(...)` and `open(...).__enter__()` are identical. The full equivalent for general context managers is given in the docs link referenced.